# Alamofire always enter on Failure status

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am trying to make a request with Alamofire and Swift 3.0 but it is always going to the failure status.

This is the code I have right now:

```
let str = "http://url/{\"user\":\"1\",\"pass\":\"1\"}"

let encodedUrl = str.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)

        Alamofire.request(encodedUrl!, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in

            switch(response.result) {
            case .success(_):

                print("Success")

                break

            case .failure(_):
                print("Failure")
                break

            }
        }
```

If I use the `encodedUrl` on `Postman` application I get the response well. It gives to me the following JSON:

```
[
  {
    "user": "1",
    "name": "peter"
  },
  {
    "user": "4",
    "name": "andrew"
  }]
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its response type is json right? not `html` or `text`? Postman displays the text formatted in most cases.

Comment: @SunilChauhan How can I know that?

Comment: In POSTMan, check here: http://prntscr.com/d5zli6
or here http://prntscr.com/d5zmac

Comment: @SunilChauhan With your second image I noticed that I had an extra String on my response. Thank you! Finally I solved it removing that String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it seems that I was retrieving an extra `String` out of the JSON because I used an `echo` on my API.

I could not see it because I had on `Postman` the option to show the response as JSON so the `String` was not being shown. I have changed it to HTML and then I was able to see the `String`.

Removing the extra `String` let me enter on the `success` status of `Alamofire`.